# Combining or Spliting Date and Time in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have 3 columns in my sql-server namely

```
Appt Time            Call Date             Call Time.
14-01-2011 09:00:00  14-01-0211 00:00:00   01-01-1980 08:52:00
```

I would like to calculate how early or late the guy come.

So I need to do `Appt Time - Call Time.`

But as the data are given, I need to change the Date part of Appt Time to 01-01-1980 or combine the Date part and Time part from Call Date and Call Time.

Any idea to do that in the shortest way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT [Appt Time] - ([Call Date] + DATEADD(day, -DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, '01-01-1980')`, [CallTime]))
```

Edit:

Explanation

- `DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, '19800101')` = days between 01 Jan 1900 and 01 Jan 1980
- `DATEADD(day, -DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, '01-01-1980'), [Call Time])` = time only

Then just add the CallDate and Calculated TimeOnly

This would be easier in SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the time portion is always stored as being on the 1st Jan 1980 (an unusual date), then you can use the following to combine the CallDate and CallTime columns together:

```
DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,'19800101',CallDate),CallTime)
```

You would then apply a further DATEDIFF (for say, minutes) to determine whether they were early or late:

```
select DATEDIFF(minute,ApptTime,DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,'19800101',CallDate),CallTime)) as EarlyLate
from <Table>
```

This will give a negative result if they were early, a positive result if they were late. The reason I prefer the `DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,'19800101',CallDate),CallTime)` formula is I use the same basic structure for most, if not all, of my date/time manipulation (you can, for instance, use something very similar for removing the time portion from a datetime value)

---

I'd also add that if you have some control over the schema, there are two changes I could suggest - the strongest would be to combine the two columns into a single datetime column. If this is not feasible (due to, for instance, being unable to alter the application that inserts/updates these values), and this type of query is going to be common, I'd suggest adding a computed column to this table, using the above formula. You'd then be able to write your queries in a more straightforward manner (and if necessary, index the column).